# Проверка на вхождение элемента в элемент

Tags: javascript, позиционирование

Имею две картинки на веб-странице одна из которых под управлением клавиатуры (при нажатии на стрелки она двигается). Cуть вопроса в том, как сделать так, чтобы наехав на вторую картинку, функция перезапускалась и элементы встали назад на свои позиции.

```js
// Js Функция движение картинки на нажатия клавиш стрелок на клавиатуре
document.onkeydown = function checkKeycode(event) {
  var keycode;
  if (!event) var event = window.event;
  if (event.keyCode) keycode = event.keyCode; // IE
  else if (event.which) keycode = event.which; // все браузеры
  if (keycode == 39) {
    $('#chel').animate({
      left: '+=20'
    });
  }
  if (keycode == 38) {
    $('#chel').animate({
      top: '-=20'
    });
  }
  if (keycode == 37) {
    $('#chel').animate({
      left: '-=20'
    });
  }
  if (keycode == 40) {
    $('#chel').animate({
      top: '+=20'
    });
  }
}
```

```css
img{
position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- html елемент картинки человека -->
<img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c837233/v837233707/1ccc6/Dq0JEyU7Hcc.jpg" id="chel" />
<!-- html елементы картинок к которым при касании должна перезапускаться функция -->
<img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c836133/v836133238/9cce/4ZxqZQaYID0.jpg" id="trap1" />
<img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1200/0*KErdtd3tFdtYwmtv." id="trap2" />
<img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c836729/v836729496/4d828/bPbQIdBX1qQ.jpg" id="trap3" />
<img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c836231/v836231635/36859/BJI17DcmZks.jpg" id="trap4" />
```

В данном фрагменте кода функция движение элемента `#chel` на движения клавиш, также я имею картинку `#trap1` которую как раз и нужно реализовать, чтобы при их соединении функция останавливалась!

Comment: Дайте еще `html` кусок вашего кода?

Comment: Дам подсказку, 
добавьте переменные которые при нажатии будут переписывать координаты расположение одной картинки(которую двигаете) и другой относительно окна браузера, если координаты по оси x или y совпадают +- ширины и высоты картинки то соответственно  снимаете обработчик события. И пропишите это всё через переменная = функции чтоб можно было обработчик удалить и добавить соответственно если координаты не совпадают. Вообщем в таком направлении двигайтесь.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#propagation

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Js Функция движение картинки на нажатия клавиш стрелок на клавиатуре
let coordinates;
let chelSize;

document.onkeydown = function checkKeycode(event) {
  let chel = $('#chel');
  if (!chelSize) {
    chelSize = {
      height: chel.outerHeight(),
      width: chel.outerWidth()
    }
  }
  if (!coordinates) {
    setCoordinatesAndSize();
  }
  var keycode;
  if (!event) var event = window.event;
  if (event.keyCode) keycode = event.keyCode; // IE
  else if (event.which) keycode = event.which; // все браузеры
  
  
  if (keycode == 39) {
    chel.animate({
      left: '+=20'
    }, checkCrossing);
  }
  if (keycode == 38) {
    chel.animate({
      top: '-=20'
    }, checkCrossing);
  }
  if (keycode == 37) {
    chel.animate({
      left: '-=20'
    }, checkCrossing);
  }
  if (keycode == 40) {
    chel.animate({
      top: '+=20'
    }, checkCrossing);
  }
  
}

function setCoordinatesAndSize() {
  let img2 = $('#trap1');
  coordinates = {
    left: img2.offset().left,
    top: img2.offset().top,
    height: img2.outerHeight(),
    width: img2.outerWidth()
  };
}

function checkCrossing() {
  let chel = $('#chel');
  if (chelSize.width + chel.offset().left >= coordinates.left &&
      chel.offset().left <= coordinates.width + coordinates.left &&
      chelSize.height + chel.offset().top >= coordinates.top &&
      chel.offset().top <= coordinates.height + coordinates.top) {
    chel.animate({
      left: '0',
      top: '0'
    });
  }
}
```

```css
img{
position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- html елемент картинки человека -->
<img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c837233/v837233707/1ccc6/Dq0JEyU7Hcc.jpg" id="chel" />
<!-- html елементы картинок к которым при касании должна перезапускаться функция -->
<img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c836133/v836133238/9cce/4ZxqZQaYID0.jpg" id="trap1" />
<img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1200/0*KErdtd3tFdtYwmtv." id="trap2" />
<img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c836729/v836729496/4d828/bPbQIdBX1qQ.jpg" id="trap3" />
<img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c836231/v836231635/36859/BJI17DcmZks.jpg" id="trap4" />
```